# Creating ready-to-use shared elements using twig

Tags: php, html, twig, assets, templating

I'm working on a project that has a lot of shared elements, e.g. footer, header, navigation, etc. I have few layouts which I extend in my views. For now, I'm loading the shared elements inside my view, but I need to provide all the assets (Dependencies) needed for each shared element inside the view I'm loading it into. I'd like to be able to skip that step and load the element which would be actually prepared for usage right away (so I wouldn't need to remember all the dependent javascript and css files, as some of them might have a few).

I was thinking about specifying all the assets needed for shared element inside the element's view, so when I include the element I need, it would load the assets "automatically", without me specifying all of them inside my view. So my question is if it's possible to do this or what's the right way to accomplish this?

Hope it will be explained even better using code:

Structure:

```
views/
- /layout/
    -> layout.twig
- /homepage/
    -> index.twig
- /shared/
    -> navigation.twig
```

Layout:

```
<!-- HTML headers, etc. -->
{% block assets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="xxx" />
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

View:

```
{% extends "layout/layout.twig" %}
{% block assets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <!-- some assets for view -->    
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% include "shared/navigation.twig" %}
    <!-- content -->
{% endblock %}
```

Shared element navigation.twig:

```
// It's not working, of course - just for better explanation of what I'm trying to approach
{% block assets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <!-- assets needed for shared element -->
{% endblock %}
<!-- rest of shared element -->
```

I guess, normally, you don't load all the assets in the views as some shared elements may have a lot of them, especially in bigger project. Also, I think it's nice to point out, that I don't really want to render the styles for them inside the `<body>`, so creating `<links>` inside the view is not a way to go for me. This is meant to work like a shared element from which you can control where your assets will be loaded and what assets will be loaded without even knowing what assets are required for each shared element. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello, have you tried to use stylesheets and javascripts blocks separately ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by that. I do separate them, when it comes to the shared element, scripts are mostly at the end of that shared element's view (which is fine, but I'd rather have them at the end of body) and the stylesheets are loaded from the view itself (which is kind of a problem for me, as I want to be able to write them into their view and get them loaded inside the head)

Comment: The best practice is explained in symfony documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating.html#including-stylesheets-and-javascripts-in-twig

Comment: Yes, this is something I'm already doing, but here's the thing... I have few  layouts, e.g. widescreen-layout, 900px-layout, etc. I extend those with my views. So let's say I have a contact view, which extends the widescreen-layout. All good for now. But I also have some "shared element", e.g. login form, which is an element used in 5 other views on webpage. I want that login to be used inside my contact view, so I do include it, but that login form needs some javascript and css to work. I want to be able to specify the js and css inside the form and get it rendered inside head for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation on `use`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/use.html):

> Horizontal reuse ... is mainly used by projects that need to make template blocks reusable without using inheritance.

`use` incorporates an external file into the current file, with the option to rename blocks to locally unique values. These locally unique values may then be injected - using `block` - into the inheritance hierarchy.

Example. Start with the base "parent":

```
<head>
  {% block assets %}
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='layout.css' />
  {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
  <div id='layout' class='content'>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
</body>
```

Define the menu, the "component" we will "reuse" later:

```
{% block assets %}
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='menu.css' />
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <div id='menu' class='content'></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Now, bring those two together. Notice how we are `extends`-ing the base, but then `use`-ing the component and reusing its blocks with `block`:

```
{% extends "layout.twig" %}

{% use "menu.twig" with assets as menu_assets, content as menu_content %}

{% block assets %}
  {{ parent() }}
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='view.css' />
  {{ block('menu_assets') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <div class='menu'>
    {{ block('menu_content') }}
  </div>
  <div id='view' class='content'></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Yields:

```
<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='layout.css' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='view.css' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='menu.css' />
</head>
<body>
  <div id='layout' class='content'>
    <div class='menu'>
      <div id='menu' class='content'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id='view' class='content'></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

It's not quite the magic of "define blocks with the same name and they all get combined", but it's pretty close. Your layout doesn't know about menu, and menu doesn't know about layout: but they both agree on blocks named "assets" and "content". The view then stitches those together into the correct inheritance form.

Comment: The great one, thank you. I was probably blind while reading the docs.